# What is the correct way to pass data from Child to Parent [Angular]

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular. I wanted to pass some data from child component to its parent component. It is a very basic mechanism. I created a minimal code to understand the concept more clearly. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-odc4sq). This one is working perfectly. But now I want to achieve this with an `input` field in child component and the passed value should be reflected in `p` tag in parent. There's is some mistake on my implementation. Can someone please check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksdqyr?file=src%2Fapp%2FParent%2Fparent.component.ts).

Comment: use EventEmitter in your child component as the @Output and Listen for the events in your parent component's template.

Comment: @AbuSufian, I'm using it already `@Output() outputToParent = new EventEmitter<string>();`

Comment: @Tanzzel you have to add listener to your Parent component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created an easy demo for you if you write anything on child if will directly reflect to the parent component. You don't have to click the button.

[**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8app2)

**UPDATED**

1. There were few issues in your code when you add 
   `<child-app></child-app>` in your parent component. You didn't add the `@Output` event listener in the child component tag.
   `<child-app (outputToParent)="GetOutputVal($event)"></child-app>`
2. In your html you have to write an event in your input field.
   `<input type="text" (keydown)="sendToParent($event.target.value)">`. The `sendToParent()` functions always emit the event on every keydown with a value of text box in the parameters.

Note: I would not recommend to use event emitters on every keydown. Because your angular application will be firing events on every keydown, which is a bad practice. The above stackblitz was for learning purpose only.

Comment: I appreciate that Ali. Can you please point out problem in my code so that next time i dont make those mistakes.

Comment: Can I use something like `onchange` in place of `keydown`. Because in actual case. I'll not be typing directly into the child text field but instead it will be populated from the database value via some program. So i want parent to get updated as oon as child text field gets its value.

Comment: Yeah you can use onChange event. But onChange only works if there is an activity on the field. Like focus out, keyup, keydown

Answer (score 1):

You have used Eventemitter in your child component to emit the updated values, but missed to add a listener on your parent component.

Parent Component

```
  valueFromChild($event: any){
    this.recievedFromChild = "Value recieved from child: "+ $event;
  }
```

HTML

```
<child (outputToParent)="valueFromChild($event)"></child>
```

Comment: Oh. So that was the problem. I'm learning Angular. I'm so sorry. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In your child component,set the value as an `eventEmitter` and emit it inside your method call.

```
@Output() childComponentValue = new EventEmitter<any>();

sendToParent() {
    this.childComponentValue.emit(<your_value>);
}
```

Now in the parent component,

```
<child (childComponentValue)="recievedFromChild($event)"></child>

recievedFromChild(event) {
    console.log(event);
    // use the emitted event
}
```