# Angular 6 - Share variable between parent and children

Tags: angular, inheritance, input, output

I am not able to find a good example of how a variable can be at the same time "input" and "output".

Basically, I have many children with inputs from the parent, but I would like to be able to edit these values and be reflected in the parent. Is there any simple way with no additional services?

Thank you in advance.

Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298370/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-angular/59298498#59298498

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to pass data from Child to Parent \[Angular\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59298370/what-is-the-correct-way-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-angular)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create both Input and Output

```
@Input() text: string;
@Output() textChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

this.textChange.emit('new value');

<child [text]="myText" (textChange)="myText = $event"></child> // myText has the new value
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood the solution that you gave me, but it was not what I was having in my mind.
After thinking several times about my implementation, I realised that it didn't have any sense and it should be an unique component, and that my problem was more about how I was "painting" the front.
Thanks for your help!